# url not being redirected to when starts with www

Tags: javascript, angular

In my application I've got a method for redirecting to a url like so:

```
openURL() {
  window.open(this.url, '_blank').focus();
}
```

This will work fine if the URL starts with a `http`, so for example, if `this.url` is set to: `https://www.example.com/...`
this will work fine.

However if it does not have the `https://` and just `wwww.example.com/.....`, then what happens is that when it opens the new tab, the url becomes `http://localhost:4200/...`

I'm just not sure why the `www` is being replaced with `http://localhost:4200/`, what could be causing this?

Comment: If a URL does _not_ start with a protocol, then it is a _relative_ URL. And relative URLs get transformed into full, absolute ones, by combining them with the URL of the current document ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just not sure why the `www` is being replaced with `http://localhost:4200/`

It's not being replaced.  The browser is simply navigating to the URL specified.  If that URL is not a complete URL then it's *relative* to the current URL.

Taking a step back, what would you expect the browser to do if you redirect to this?:

- `index.html`

How about this?:

- `www.html`

Or this?:

- `www.com`

Or this?:

- `www.index.com`

The lines between what we *intuitively* consider a domain vs. a file name are blurry enough.  Consider that the browser doesn't share our sense of intuition and it simply has no way of *guessing* what you meant.  So it's going to redirect to exactly what was *specified*.

In this case the *protocol* (scheme) isn't required, but the root specifier before the domain is.  So this:

- `wwww.example.com`

Should at least be this:

- `//wwww.example.com`